# Is there a way to catch all flows exceptions?

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to create a way to catch both kind of exceptions that are thrown by node-red runtime, node.error('xxxx', msg) and unexpected ones/throw new Error... ones.

Is there any way I can hook up to the runtime to listen to all exceptions thrown that also includes the complete msg object?

P.D., I'm using vanilla node-red embedded into an existing express app.

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` node can be set to catch all errors or just the ones from a specific node.

It does depend on the nodes throwing the errors with `node.error()` to use it properly (it needs to include the `msg` object after the error message).

Comment: But it is a way that a catch node in one flow to catch all exceptions thrown by all the other flows? Because I've seen that when a node throws an exception, the method that handles the error lookup all catch nodes of the current flow